# jQuery: Return all matched elements not only one matched element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a table which each td has title, id, and lang attributes. I want all lang of all elements that matched specified title and id. So I tried:

```
var lossy = $("[title="+hicode+"][id="+hiwidth+"]").attr("lang");
alert(lossy);
```

But this return only first matched element.

Any idea to return all matched elements in array or even string is still OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `each()` function to loop through all of the matched elements...

This code defines an array, loops through all of of the matched elements and adds the lang attr to the array.

```
var results=new Array();

$("[title="+hicode+"][id="+hiwidth+"]").each(function(index){
  results[index] = $(this).attr("lang");
});

alert(results);
```

Also, here is an example that loops through divs and collects the id attr: http://jsfiddle.net/tSmMj/

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
var lossy = $("[title="+hicode+"][id="+hiwidth+"]").map(function() { return $(this).attr("lang"); });
alert(lossy);
```

I'm using the map function that translate all items in an array or array-like object to another array of items. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: From jQuery doco: "As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to get() the returned object to work with a basic array.". You may want to add a `.get()` to the end of `.map()` call.

Comment: Thank you both of you. It works after adding `.map()` as Dysaster said.

Comment: To get a true array you need to do .toArray() on the result of the .map() call

Answer (score 2):

The standard jQuery function, `$(selector)`, does return all matching elements. Your problem is right here:

```
[id="+hiwidth+"]
```

You seem to have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute and that is not allowed; `id` attributes should be unique within each page or you will get undefined behavior. In your case, the browser is only returning the first element that has the `id` you're looking for.

So you need to fix your HTML and then fix your selector to match your corrected HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I will avoid using multiple elements with the same id attributes.